# Como defino operator= para uma struct em c++?

Tags: c++, struct, operadores

Tenho a estrutura a seguir:

```
struct PATH {

  vector<ARCO_TEMPO> rota;
  set<int> rotaAux;
  float COST;
  int nArcosVoyage;
  vector<bool> VisitedNodes;
  vector<vector<bool>> VisitedVertices;
  int head_no;
  int head_time;
  int tail_no;
  int tail_time;
  float reducedCost;
  float duracao;
  int auxNumAircrafts;

};
```

Como faço para criar o operator = para essa estrutura?
Pensei que pudesse fazer assim:

```
PATH& PATH::operator=(const PATH& p1) {

  COST = p1.COST - cFixo[aa]*p1.auxNumAircrafts;
  reducedCost = p1.reducedCost - cFixo[aa]*p1.auxNumAircrafts;
  auxNumAircrafts = p1.auxNumAircrafts;

  nArcosVoyage = p1.nArcosVoyage;
  head_no = p1.head_no;
  head_time = p1.head_time;
  tail_no = p1.tail_no;
  tail_time = p1.tail_time;
  duracao = p1.duracao;

  for (int i = 0; i < p1.rota.size(); i++) {
    rota[i].a.i = p1.rota[i].a.i; 
    rota[i].a.j = p1.rota[i].a.j; 
    rota[i].slotTimeU = p1.rota[i].slotTimeU; 
    rota[i].slotTimeV = p1.rota[i].slotTimeV; 
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    VisitedNodes[i] = p1.VisitedNodes[i];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 1; j <= max_slot; j++) {
        VisitedVertices[i][j] = p1.VisitedVertices[i][j];
    }
  }

  rotaAux = p1.rotaAux;

  return *this;

};
```

Porém, aparece o seguinte erro:

> error: definition of implicitly-declared ‘PATH& PATH::operator=(const
>   PATH&)’ PATH& PATH::operator=(const PATH& p1);

Como posso concertar isso?

Answer (score 3):

Você tem de declarar o método na classe ou struct se quiser implementá-lo. Inclua

```
PATH& operator=(const PATH& p1);
```

dentro da declaração do struct, junto com as variáveis-membros.

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta. Isso funcionou.
Porém, percebi que preciso de uma variável que não é global na definição do operator= (max_slot).
Achei que pudesse apenas mudar o cabeçario da função de forma que:
PATH& operator=(const PATH& p1, int max_slot);
Porém, quando faço isso, aparece o erro: 
 error: ‘PATH& PATH::operator=(const PATH&, int)’ must take exactly one argument PATH& operator=(const PATH& p1, int max_slot);
Tem como concertar isso?

Comment: Não, uma atribuição sempre aceita apenas um argumento. Você teria de criar uma função com nome (sem ser operator) para aceitar dois argumentos.

Answer (score 2):

Se você quer apenas copiar os valores sem fazer nada além disso, e assumindo [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), você pode simplesmente fazer

```
PATH &operator=(const PATH &) = default;
```

dentro da struct, sem precisar definir um corpo. Sem [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), você deve declarar e definir o construtor de cópia manualmente, como na [resposta de @epx](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/288627/39641).